# <Header> elements (<Avatar>,<Text>) get stacked under phone navigation bar - react - native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, react-native

I'am building an phone application , but recently i bumped into a problem . My elements in the  section get stacked up under each other and under my phone navigation screen . Normally they should be exported in a row and they should be align in the center. I've tried to fix the bug , but not success until now . I will be glad if someone can give me a heads up how should i resolve this problem .

[image: Better image but still not perfect.]

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leftComponentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

....

leftComponent={
  <View style={styles.leftComponentStyle}>
    ...
  </View>
}
```

[image: Elements overlapped under phone menu bar]

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { Image , View , Text , TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Header , Avatar  } from 'react-native-elements';

import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import AppContainer from './navigation/MainTabNavigator';


export default class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return(

        <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
          <Header
            backgroundColor='#e2e2e2'
            placement='left'
          leftComponent={
            <View>
              <Avatar
              rounded
              size='small'
              title='JD'
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              />
              <Text>John Doe.</Text>
            </View>
          }
          rightComponent={
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 80,
                height: 60,
              }}
              source={require=('./assets/images/Shootlog.png')}
            />
          }
           />
           <AppContainer/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a style to View inside the leftComponent prop. Look into the [doc](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/docs/header.md). If you pass a element you must care of it's styling if nesting is present.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leftComponentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

....

leftComponent={
  <View style={styles.leftComponentStyle}>
    ...
  </View>
}
```

Comment: i've posted the result in the main question . Thank you it's not perfect but it is almost .

Comment: Yeah. No issues. Question is clear. So don't need to worry. Just add flex styling to View wrapped inside leftComponent and it will work.

Comment: Sorry mate still don't get it how to add flex to a view because it has a styling once .

Comment: I've added flex:1 to const style = StyleSheet.create , but the result stay the same

Comment: Try changing leftContainerStyle prop for header component.

Answer (score 1):

Myabe add these styles to view wrapping avatar and name?

`<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} >`

Where alignItems should align them horizontally and justifyContent center them vertically

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make your code as blow

`leftComponent={
            <View style = {{flexDrection: 'row','justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
            >
              <Avatar
              rounded
              size='small'
              title='JD'
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              />
              <Text>John Doe.</Text>
            </View>
          }`